# Checking files upload on s3 with Jmeter

Tags: java, rest, amazon-s3, jmeter

I have an asynchronous rest endpoint which will always trigger 200 as return code after few milliseconds. My backend anyway will start a slow computation which will end after some seconds in a file uploaded to s3.

I would like to test it with jmeter to measure the latency scaling with concurrent users, but I need jmeter to wait until the file is successfully loaded on s3. Is it something that can be achieved or I need to write my own script to do that?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to check the file presence in the S3 bucket in the loop.

With regards to checking if the file is there or not there are 2 ways:

1. Use [S3 REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html), no external programs libraries will be required
2. Use [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) tool from the [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)
3. Use [AWS Java SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingTheMPJavaAPI.html#TestingJavaSamples) from the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

The whole logic can be wrapped into the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) so you could get the cumulative time from sending the request to your endpoint till the file appears in the S3 bucket.